# Finding where tangent plane of ellipsoid intersects x-axis

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image]

This is the work I have so far:

$f_x = 2x_0,\ \ \  x_0 = x_0 \ \ \ \ \ \ f_x = 2x_0$

$f_y = 6y_0, \ \ \ \ \ y_0 = 0 \ \ \ \ \ \ f_y = 0$

$f_z = 20z_0, \ \ \ \ \ z_0 = 0 \ \ \ \ \ \ f_z = 0 \\$

$f_x(x-x_0) + f_y(y-y_0) + f_z(z-z_0) = 0$

$2x_0(1 - x_0) = 0$

$2x_0 - 2x_0^2$

$x = 1$

Apparently, the answer is actually e) but I am unsure of what I am doing wrong.

Comment: evaluate the derivatives at $ (1, -1, 1 )$ not $( x_0, 0, 0)$

Comment: Why would that be so? In my textbook the equation of a tangent plane is written as $f_x(P_0)(x - x_0) + f_y(P_0)(y - y_0) + f_z(P_0)(z - z_0) = 0$. I understand that switching it to (1, -1, 1) will give the right answer, I just don't understand why if the formula given in my textbook calls for $(x_0, 0, 0)$

Comment: In your textbook's formula, $x_0$ is the $x$-coordinate of the point on the surface given by $f(x,y,z)=0$, and so on for $y_0$ and $z_0$. You are trying to make those variables  to be the intersection of the tangent plane with the $x$-axis, quite a different thing. You need to first find the equation of the tangent plane, using the book's formula with $x_0=1,y_0=-1,z_0=1$, and then solve that equation for $x$ after substituting $y=0,z=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unfortunate that the question named the x-intercept $x_0$ which appears as a symbol in your formula making reference to the point on the ellipsoid. The question might be clearer if they said the x-intercept was at $(a,0,0)$ and asked you to find $a$

you should use $P_0=(x_0, y_0, z_0)=(1,-1,1)$

so the equation of the tangent plane is $2(x-1) -6(y+1)+20(z-1)=0$ and the x-intercept is at $(14,0,0)$

Comment: Quick question: shouldn't the 3(z-1) actually be 20(z-1)?

Comment: I got the equation $2(x−1)−6(y+1)+20(z−1)=0. \\ f_x = 2x = 2(1) = 2. \\ f_z = 20z = 20(1) = 2$

Comment: you are correct about the $20(z-1)$ I have edited my answer accordingly

Comment: For Future Viewers: I made an error in the original post. The answer was actually e) and the correct equation is  2(x−1)−6(y+1)+20(z−1)=0.